# Сan i use extend from module scss style file?

Tags: sass, extends, css-modules, scss-mixins

## I am trying to achieve this:

I declare such an extension in file `button.module.scss`

```
.button {
  @extend %button;
}
```

and then try to use it in file `icon.module.scss`

```
.icon {
  %button & {
    fill: red;
  }
}
```

I tried to import scss module `button.module.scss` into file `icon.module.scss` like this:

```
@import '../../components/UI/button/button.module.scss'
```

this method does not give an error, but does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were going for. But this worked for me.

```
.button {
  fill: red;
}

.icon {
    @extend .button;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works if we use the extend in the same style module as the class we use the extend in, but I would like to use the extend in a different style module

Comment: I think your problem might be solved here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inherit-a-class-to-another-file-in-sass/